# How to get GuildMember data from a User through a mention

Tags: discord.js

I am making a "user info" command that returns the user's Discord username, their ID, their server join date and whether or not they are online. I am able to display all the information through `user.id`, `user.username`, and `user.presence.status`. But when I try to use `user.joinedAt` I get `undefined` in the display.

I know this is because the `User` class and the `GuildMember` class are not the same, and that the `GuildMember` class contains a `User` object.
But my problem is: how I could get the `.joinedAt` data from my user mention?

Here is my current code:

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first();
let embed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
  .setColor('#4286f4')
  .addField("Full Username:", `${user.username}#${user.discriminator}`)
  .addField("User ID:", `${user.id}`)
  .addField("Server Join Date:", `${user.joinedAt}`)
  .addField("Online Status:", `${user.presence.status}`)
  .setThumbnail(user.avatarURL);

message.channel.send(embed);
```

Answer (score 5):

Here's the code for my user info command:

```js
if (msg.split(" ")[0] === prefix + "userinfo") {
  //ex `member @Rinkky
  let args = msg.split(" ").slice(1) // gets rid of the command
  let rMember = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first() || message.guild.members.get(args[0])) // Takes the user mentioned, or the ID of a user
  let micon = rMember.displayAvatarURL // Gets their Avatar

    if(!rMember) 
      return message.reply("Who that user? I dunno him.") // if there is no user mentioned, or provided, it will say this

      let memberembed = new Discord.RichEmbed()
      .setDescription("__**Member Information**__")
      .setColor(0x15f153)
      .setThumbnail(micon) // Their icon
      .addField("Name", `${rMember.username}#${rMember.discriminator}`) // Their name, I use a different way, this should work
      .addField("ID", rMember.id) // Their ID
      .addField("Joined at", rMember.joinedAt) // When they joined

      await message.channel.send(memberembed)
};
```

This will send an embed of their user info, this is my current code and

```
rMember.joinedAt
```

does work for me.

edit:
After looking at your question again, I found out I didn't need to post everything, you can't get the joined at because it's just the mention. Try this:

```js
let user = message.guild.member(message.mentions.users.first())
```

Should work

Answer (score 2):

You can technically find it by fetching getting the member from the guild and then using `GuildMember.joinedAt`: since the `User` class represents the user in every guild, you will always need the `GuildMember` to get info about a specific guild.

```js
let user = message.mentions.users.first(),
  member;
if (user) member = message.guild.member(user);
if (member) embed.addField("Server Join Date:", `${member.joinedAt}`);
```

With this said, I would not suggest you to do that, since it's not really efficient. Just take the mention from the members' collection and then take the user from that.

```js
let member = message.mentions.members.first(),
  user;
if (member) user = member.user;
```

The downside of this is that you can't use it if you want your command to be executable from the DMs too. In that case you should use the first method.

Answer (score 1):

```
const member = message.channel.guild.members.cache.find(member => member.user == message.mentions.users.first())
```